# How do I redirect to a page of my site taking the trailing slash as the language parameter using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, slash

I have this rule which is not redirecting properly:

```
#redirect from www.mysite.com/page-NAME/es to www.mysite.com/public/index.php?page=NAME/es
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule page-(.*)/es$ public/index.php?page=$1&lang=es [L]
```

Internally the parameter page is not getting received so the site shows the home page instead. I am not sure if I have this rule wrong or if it is just conflicting with the other rules which are working perfectly, or if it is an order problem.

All help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Below is the full htaccess file on the root of my site, in case you want to take a look at it.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

DirectoryIndex index.php

#Adds www to the domain
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#redirect from www.mysite.com/es to www.mysite.com/public/index.php?lang=es
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule /es$ public/index.php?lang=es [L]

#redirect from www.mysite.com/en to www.mysite.com/public/index.php?lang=en
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule /en$ public/index.php?lang=en [L]

#redirect from www.mysite.com/ to www.mysite.com/public/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L]

#redirect from www.mysite.com/page-NAME/es to www.mysite.com/public/index.php?page=NAME/es
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule page-(.*)/es$ public/index.php?page=$1&lang=es [L]

#redirect from www.mysite.com/page-NAME to www.mysite.com/public/index.php?page=NAME
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule page-(.*)$ public/index.php?page=$1 [L]

#redirect from www.mysite.com/ to www.mysite.com/public/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: UPDATE: seems like it is a conflict problem because if I remove the rules to redirect  www.mysite.com/es and www.mysite.com/en the pages load properly, so I guess the question would be how do I make all this rules work together

Answer (score 0):

ok found the problem seems, it was indeed an order issue, this is way seems to work, hopefully this helps someone with the same issue

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

DirectoryIndex index.php

#Adds www to the domain
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#redirect from www.mysite.com/page-NAME/es to www.mysite.com/public/index.php?page=NAME/es
RewriteRule page-(.*)/es$ public/index.php?page=$1&lang=es [L]

#redirect from www.mysite.com/page-NAME to www.mysite.com/public/index.php?page=NAME
RewriteRule page-(.*)$ public/index.php?page=$1 [L]


#redirect from www.mysite.com/es to www.mysite.com/public/index.php?lang=es
RewriteRule /es public/index.php?lang=es [L]

#redirect from www.mysite.com/en to www.mysite.com/public/index.php?lang=en
RewriteRule /en public/index.php?lang=en [L]

#redirect from www.mysite.com/ to www.mysite.com/public/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L]


#redirect from www.mysite.com/ to www.mysite.com/public/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```